# How can I add children to a stackpanel and keep my grid.row below the stackpanel visible while scrolling through the stackpanel?

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have an UWP Grid with a Stackpanel and a button. Programmatically I add children to the stackpanel. If there are too many children the outer grid becomes scrollable and the stackpanel and the button move when scrolling.
I want the button to stay at the bottom of the screen (always visible) and the stackpanel to become scrollable.

Here is my xaml Code.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="panel" Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button x:Name="ucBottomMenu" Grid.Row="1" Height="60"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your above code is the all XAML code on your page, the button control should be always visible. You just need to use a `ScrollViewer` control to wrap the stackPanel, then only the child elements in stackPanel can scroll.

The XAML looks like the following:

```
<Page
x:Class="AppScroll.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppScroll"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel x:Name="panel" Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
        <Button x:Name="ucBottomMenu" Grid.Row="1" Height="60" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```